# Are required fields encoded more efficiently in Google Protocol Buffers?

Tags: protocol-buffers

My structure contains a repeated field that is a small structure on its own, containing two integers only:

```
   message Bin {
     optional int32 slot = 1;
     optional int32 count = 2;
   }

   message Histogram {
     repeated Bin bin = 1; // Might be about 200 - 400 bins.
   }
```

Would the `Bin` be encoded more efficiently if I define `slot` and `count` as `required` instead?

I think that in case of unlikely changes I can redefine the `Bin` message completely and modify `Histogram` as

```
repeated Bin2 bin2 = 2;
```

(`repeated` fields can be dropped)

Comment: No, Before each field there is a Field_Number/Field_Type field followed by the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, basically; the [encoding details are here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding), but whether that is `optional` or `required`, eash of `slot`/`count` is going to be a varint field-header/wire-type combo followed by a varint of the value. `optional` vs `required` doesn't change the format: it simply changes whether the value is required. Interesting, there's also actually no difference between a `repeated` value with exactly one value vs an `optional` / `required` value that is present. The only time this *does* change is for "packed" encodings of repeated primitives. If you have **lots** of them, you could actually get more efficient data from either 1 or 2 packed arrays instead:

```
message Histogram {
  repeated int32 slots = 1 [packed=true];
  repeated int32 counts = 2 [packed=true];
}
```

The above is less *convenient*, but more *efficient* on the wire. You could of course do the same thing with a single double-length array:

```
message Histogram {
  repeated int32 slotsAndCounts = 1 [packed=true];
}
```

A *normal* repeated field containing 5 items works as:

- field header, value, field header, value, field header, value, field header, value, field header, value

A *packed* repeated field containing 5 items works as:

- field header, length, value, value, value, value, value